# php how to include some variable from another file

Tags: php, variables, get

say i have a main file :

```
        <form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
        <input title="Masukkan kalimat disini" type="text"  />
            <?php   
           //main.php 
            $a = ...;
            $b = ....;
    ?>
```

and included file

```
  <?php
//included.php
    include 'main.php';
    ?>
```

certainly included.php file will load all parts of main.php, so how to include some variable, such as include $a only, and not showing the textfield

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programming is just driving your thoughts :)

So what i want to say that your question is how you can include just some part of an included file and my answer is that you can achieve that by doing a test each time the main file is included from withing this file to see if the file is included internally or not and you can be more precise in a way that you split your main file into block which are loaded due suitable variable

Take a look for this workaround and hope you will understand what i mean

Supposing we have the main file named main.php contains that contents

```
<?php
     echo 'I am a java programmer';
     echo 'I know also PHP very well';
     echo 'When the jquery is my preferred toast !';
?>
```

now i have three external files that will include that file each file is specific for one of this 3 programming language

So i will create my 3 files in this way :

File : java.php

```
<?php
    $iamjavadevelopper = 1;
    include_once("main.php");
?>
```

File : phpfav.php

```
<?php
    $iamphpdevelopper = 1;
    include_once("main.php");
?>
```

File : jquery.php

```
<?php
    $iamjquerydevelopper = 1;
    include_once("main.php");
?>
```

and my main.php will be coded in this way

```
<?php
    if(isset($iamjavadevelopper))
        echo 'I am a java programmer';
    if(isset($iamphpdevelopper))
        echo 'I know also PHP very well';
    if(isset($iamjquerydevelopper))
     echo 'When the jquery is my preferred toast !';
?>
```

By this way each one of our three external files will show just a part of the included file :)

Hope that was clear and helpfull :) Any help needed i am just ready :)

Comment: @user2192076 : For nothing ! But please if you find my answer is the helpfull answer mark it as the best answer and mark your question as answered :) And don't hesitate to ask for any help i am just here :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include just a variable (or set of variables), they need to be in their own file. Ideally, you would also put them in a different scope (such as a class), so they're not cluttering up the global namespace.

E.g.,

**config.php:**

```
<?php
    class Foo {
        public $a = "I am a variable";
        public $b = "I am also a variable";
        const $c = "I am an immutable variable!";
    }
?>
```

**main.php:**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
<input title="Masukkan kalimat disini" type="text" />
<?php
    @require_once "config.php";
?>
```

**included.php:**

```
<?php
    @require_once "config.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing you are including the page, you will beable to use your set variables which are set on a different page (if that makes sense)

*Global.inc.php*

```
<?php
   $Var_1 = "This will work"; 
   $Var_2 = "Another set variable.";
?>
```

*index.php*

```
<?php
   include "Global.inc.php";
   echo $var_1; // This will output 'This will work'
?>
```

As you have included a file, all the contents will be usable; You just have to work with the variables that you want. There will be no performance hits for including a 300 line page, to use less than 50 lines of code for example.

*Update:*

Show within HTML Structures:

Inputs:

```
<input type='text' name='Name' value='<?php echo $Var_1; ?>'>
```

Text Box:

```
<textarea><?php echo $Var_1; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to show an example on how to use these within HTML Structures, if this is not what your looking for then let me know